# Avoid shell=True with command line arguments in python

Tags: python, shell

I want to run inside my test.py script a shell command line which takes a couple of arguments. The test.py is run as:

```
python test.py filename file_2 int
```

The test.py looks inside analogous to this:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
file_2 = sys.argv[2]
num = sys.argv[3]

subprocess.call("xargs /bin/bash  build/install/programme/bin/programme option -n "+num+" --csv-file="+str(filename)+" -c files/"+str(file_2)+ "< /tmp/my_ids_"+str(file_2)+"_"+str(num),shell=True)
```

The point is that I want to *avoid using shell=True*, but all the options I found so far do not provide a good solution for the arguments I am adding in the command line.

So far I have tried different options via splitting it with `Popen`, as for example:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
file_2 = sys.argv[2]
num = sys.argv[3]

subprocess.Popen(["xargs","/bin/bash","build/install/programme/bin/programme","option","-n", str(num),"--csv-file=",str(filename),"-c","files/",str(file_2),"<",str("/tmp/my_ids_"+str(file_2)+"_"+str(num))])
```

But I got no working results. Also tried with `shlex`, but again in the documentation I saw no options for being able to add arguments in the command.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `shell=True` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Because it's inefficient and prone to quoting errors. It's much better to pass a list of string arguments directly to `execve` (or whichever member of the `exec` family is being used) where possible.

Comment: @PedroLobito, ...I'd go beyond "quoting errors" -- generating commands through string concatenation and evaluating those strings as code makes your software vulnerable to injection attacks. Think of [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) -- he has a brother named `Johnny $(rm -rf $HOME)'$(rm -rf $HOME)'`.

Comment: @PedroLobito, ...similarly, vulnerability to [ShellShock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) was conferred by way of invoking a shell in just this way. Use `shell=False`, and you don't have a shell involved -- one less thing to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code was equivalent to running the following bash command:

```
xargs \
  /bin/bash \
  build/install/programme/bin/programme \
  option \
  -n            "$int" \
  "--csv-file=" "$filename" \
  -c            "files/"           "${file_2}" \
  '<'           "/tmp/my_ids_${file_2}_${int}"
```

That wouldn't have worked either, and for all the same reasons.

---

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
file_2 = sys.argv[2]
num = int(sys.argv[3])

subprocess.Popen([
  "xargs",
  "/bin/bash",
  "build/install/programme/bin/programme",
  "option",
  "-n", str(num),
  "--csv-file=%s" % filename,
  "-c", "files/%s" % file_2,
], stdin=open("/tmp/my_ids_%s_%s" % (file_2, num), 'r')
```

Note the differences:

- A single argument is always passed as a single list member. That means `--csv-file=filename` is all one thing, and that the prefix `files/` and the string contained in the variable `file_2` need to be passed within the same list element.
- Redirections (`<`) are instructions **to the shell**, not arguments to your program. You thus can't use them here, but should use other options (such as the `stdin` and `stdout` arguments to `Popen`) to simulate their effect.
- `int` is the name of the integer type; using the variable name `num` keeps the original name available.

Comment: Maybe change `int` to `num` and add a note about clobbering the built-in.

Comment: @DavidCullen, good call. I thought about that for a moment earlier but decided to put it off -- since what we're doing here is creating a learning resource, though, I really should have taken the time to address it up-front.

Comment: I also changed it in the original post, thanks for the advise